# Cherokee-like WebUI for nginx

Tags: nginx, graphical-user-interface, cherokee

Is there any nginx module that will provide Cherokee-like web administration panel? It will be very helpful to manage virtual servers and another stuff.

I'm looking for it because I love nginx for this speed and simplicity but Cherokee has great management WebUI.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not aware of any nginx *module*, but there are some cPanel-like admin panels that support nginx.  Right off the top of my head, I know of [Froxlor](http://froxlor.org/) and [ehcp](http://ehcp.net/).  I think cPanel supports nginx via a plugin and from some researching I did a few months back I read that Plesk was going to support it, as well.

Comment: I would not recommend to use cPanel with nginx! If you need an nginx GUI choose froxlor. I've reviewed the two most used modules adding nginx to cPanel and I was shocked by the lack of security in those concepts as well as the poor code quality. Besides this at least one of the just adds nginx as a proxy for the cPanel driven apache. So better choose a panel that supports it directly